# How can I specify what happens when someone calls my fieldtype without any further dot chains?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype

So, I'm in the process of building a fieldtype, and I'd like to output an HTML element and some javascript when a developer calls my plugin like this:

```
{{ entry.fieldtypeHandle }}
```

The field returns an object with other methods/properties on it, but I'd like to specifically provide something different when a developer calls my fieldtype without any other chaining.

I've tried pass a class with a `__toString()` method, but it just returns a string. (I don't know what I expected, honestly.) I also know that coupling the HTML output with the class *seems* a bit dirty, even if that did work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`entry.myFieldHandle` will return whatever the field type’s [prepValue()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/fieldtypes/IFieldType#prepValue-detail) function returns.

If you *always* want that to be HTML, then prepValue() can just return the HTML as a string or \Twig_Markup object via [TemplateHelper::getRaw()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/TemplateHelper#getRaw-detail) so devs don't have to type `|raw` when outputting the value.

If you want it to be an object that supports sub-properties and methods, then have prepValue() return the object. Give the class a `__toString()` method, which defines the string that should be returned when the object is treated like a string. Behind the scenes, `__toString()` is what will be called when a template has `{{ entry.myFieldHandle }}`. But note that this is a PHP construct and PHP mandates that the method returns an actual string, so you can’t return a \Twig_Markup object here. Devs will have to type `{{ entry.myFieldHandle|raw }}` to prevent Twig from escaping the HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that Craft did some magic with the result of the toString method, but it looks like I'll just have to put what I wanted to do into a method on the object that's returned. Thanks for the clarification!